# Waiting for bot to be ready after deployment

Tags: azure, botframework

Situation 1
I wrote my own bot framework and deploy to Azure,
the Test in Web Chat shown me "Waiting for bot to be ready after deployment".

Situation 2
I downloaded the source code from Azure bot Services,after that I deploy back to Azure, the Web Chat shown me "Waiting for bot to be ready after deployment".

[image: Waiting for bot to be ready]

Comment: You can test from the dev.botframework.com/bots?id=[your bot id], MyBots menu site after deployment. Not sure why not loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What fixed it for me was changing Destination URL in Publish Settings to https. For some reason default is http.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I also faced this issue and this is how I solved it.

1. Changed my publish settings to have `Remove additional files at destination` checked. This is an important step because when you provisioned a new web app bot, it will already have some files in the location. So when you publish your code, it will be placed along with the code files which already exists. You can also test it by navigating to the `/api/messages` url. If this gives you error, then this is most likely the case.
2. I also updated all the NuGet dependencies.
3. The other thing that caused me a bit of issue was the App Password. The app password in your web.config should match the one which is already generated for your BOT. Do not create a new password from the bot management page. If you did that then make sure that you change/update the password in web app bot application settings and also in the web.config file. When you host the bot, by default it will use the `Application Id` and `Application Password` which were generated automatically. You can see these values in the `Web App Bot` service type which is under the section `App Service Settings>Application Settings`. Scroll down to the bottom and you will see these two settings. Copy the values of `Application Id`  and `Application Password` and update them in the Web.config file.

Hope this help!

Comment: +1 for the "Remove additional files at destination"  2 hours of my life I will never get back.  Thanks!!

Comment: And a +1 for "The app password in your web.config should match the one which is already generated for your BOT." Cheers!

Comment: Indeed the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in web.config are blank when you download the project.

Comment: Where can you change the publish setting to remove additional files at destination?

Answer (score 2):

I had missing node packages that I wasn't aware of. I found the errors in the output logs at https://[bot-name-here].scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/:vs.output

Or you can Navigate to this by going to Build -> Click 'Show output' (or Shift+Command+U) (its the 5th icon in the left hand side menu on the Build window)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas to troubleshoot for people having the same error:

- Check that the server hosting your bot is actually running. If https://YOUR_BOT.azurewebsites.net is timing out, then your server is not running, check your config
- Check if you have logs in the App Service: Enable everything under App Service > Diagnostic logs, then go to `App Service > Log Stream`.
- Check potential errors under `Web App Bot > Channels > Web Chat > Issues`
- Check that the files on the server look ok by going to `App Service > App Service Editor (Preview)`
- Close all your browsers, especially if they have been running for a long time and/or you have been changing a lot of config/files recently

I fixed the issue by using a combination of those points

Answer (score 0):

I had the window open for a few days, and "Test in Web Chat" would just show "Waiting for bot to be ready" and the juggling progress indicator, forever.  I duplicated the tab and it came right up.  I think my session may have expired or something, because any new, duplicated tab, I could bring the bot up in just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by, in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, setting the .bot file's property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"."

The details: The bot worked fine locally in the emulator. After deploying to Azure (continuous deployment), "Test in Web Chat" hung with "Waiting for bot to be ready". (Would be nice if it detected and reported errors.)

After setting up Azure storage, turning on Azure logging, discovering the FileNotFoundException, inspecting with Resource Explorer, and deploying multiple bot versions, I isolated the cause. This document really helped me troubleshoot:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio#a-nameapptracelogsacreate-and-view-application-trace-logs

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem but the solution I have is totally different from the suggestions above.

I created my Knowledge Base and Web App Bot purely using the portal. The problem lies with the configuration. As of writing, the Bot Template: **Node.js > Question and Answer** does not work. I needed to create a new Web App Bot and I selected instead **C# > Question and Answer**.

That fixed my problem and allowed me to use the *Test in Web Chat* feature.